# issue while extending InputStream class

Tags: java, inputstream, datainputstream, bufferedinputstream

I am trying to extend InputStream class and use customized read() methods.
This is my class snapshot:

```
class MyClass
{    
     /** Input stream */
     private final MyInputStream in = new MyInputStream();
     /**get the InputStream
     public InputStream getInputStream()
     {
         return in;
     }

     /** Inner class for MyInputStream */
     class MyInputStream extends InputStream
     {
         //here i am keeping implementation of read methods
         public synchronized int read( byte b[] ) throws IOException
         {
         //..................
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is my client class

```
public class MyClient {
     //InStreams
     protected BufferedInputStream mBufInStream;
     protected DataInputStream mInStream;

     public int read(byte[] buffer)
     {
           MyClass obj1 =  new MyClass();
           mBufInStream = new BufferedInputStream(obj1.getInputStream());
           mInStream = new DataInputStream(mBufInStream);
           try
           {
               int i = mBufInStream.read(buffer);
               return i;
           }
           catch (IOException ex)
           {
               return -1;
           }
     }

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        MyClient cl1 = new MyClient();
        int ret = 0;
        byte[] data = {};

        ret = cl1.read(data);

     } 
 }
```

What i wanted to do is call my read method of MyInputStream Class when cl1.read is done.

I don't know what i am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the DataInputStream object using MyInputStream and got it working. Here is the updated code:

```
public class MyClient {
 //InStreams
 protected DataInputStream mInStream;

 public int read(byte[] buffer)
 {
       MyClass obj1 =  new MyClass();
       mInStream = new DataInputStream(obj1.getInputStream());
       try
       {
           int i = mInStream.read(buffer);
           return i;
       }
       catch (IOException ex)
       {
           return -1;
       }
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    MyClient cl1 = new MyClient();
    int ret = 0;
    byte[] data = {};

    ret = cl1.read(data);

 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending input stream class then you will need to give the concrete definition for the following method:

```
public abstract int read() throws IOException
```

Your class has the read method with the signature as:

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

So please implement `read()` in addition to `read(byte[] b)`. I have made some modifications and it works now...

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyClient {
     //InStreams
     protected BufferedInputStream mBufInStream;
     protected DataInputStream mInStream;

     public int read(byte[] buffer) {
           MyClass obj1 =  new MyClass();
        //   mBufInStream = new BufferedInputStream(obj1.getInputStream());
         //  mInStream = new DataInputStream(mBufInStream);
           try {
               int i = obj1.getInputStream().read(buffer);
               return i;
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               return -1;
           }
     }

     public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClient cl1 = new MyClient();
        int ret = 0;
        byte[] data = {'a','b'};

        ret = cl1.read(data);
        System.out.println(ret);
     } 
 }



import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

class MyClass {

     /** Input stream */
     private final MyInputStream in = new MyInputStream();
     //get the InputStream
     public InputStream getInputStream() {
         return in;
     }

     class MyInputStream extends InputStream {
         //here i am keeping implementation of read methods
         public int read( byte b[] ) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Inside my read()");
            return b.length;
         //..................
         }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: yes  have added the read function as well.. follwoing are the functions i have implemented in MyClass:                                                               - - 1. public synchronized int read() throws IOException 2. public synchronized int read( byte b[] ) throws IOException 3. public synchronized int read( byte b[], int off, int len ) throws IOException 4. public synchronized int read( byte b[], int off, int len, byte t[] ) throws IOException 5. public synchronized int available() throws IOException

Comment: yes it was working this way but i wanted to make it work with BufferedInputStream / DataInputStream. is it possible at all that i use read() operations on DataInputStream instance and implementation from MyClass gets executed?

Comment: At compile time reference decides which method will be called and at runtime , Object actually decides which method will be called. In this case , mBufInStream is of Super class and object is also of BufferedInputStream , so at runtime jvm considers the object and overriding method in class BufferedInputStream is called.

Comment: Yes, actually DataInputStream perform the read operation on underlying Inputstream object. I got it working by creating DataInputStream Object using MyInputStream Object. Thanks though.

Comment: Hey are you sure that the read method of DataInputStream was called when you modified the code as mentioned above i.e. by doing ->   mInStream.read(buffer);                                                                           I do not believe read() of MyInputStream will be called by using the reference variable mInStream, in fact I tried the same code and the read method of DataInputStream is being called not the read method of                                           MyInputStream.

Comment: yes actually DataInputStream class will call read(byte b[], int off, int len) of Inputstream. it adds '0' as offset and length of byte array and then call the read method of underlying InputStream object. as i had defined this one also so i got it working. it calls "public int read(byte b[], int off, int len)" of MyInputStream class.